# Socket attributes undefined on disconnect

Tags: node.js, socket.io, undefined, disconnect

I'm making a chatroom using socket.io, express, and nodejs. So far login, logout, and message events are working fine. However, accessing the 'userid' attribute of a disconnecting client is giving me an undefined error. I store a list of users on the server and set their status to 0 if offline.

```
"use strict";

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('./node_modules/socket.io').listen(server);

var users = [];
var messages = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {       

    // various event functions

    socket.on('logout', function(fn){
        var username = socket.name;
        fn('true');

        users[socket.userid].status = 0; // 0: OFFLINE

        socket.emit('leave lobby', function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

        messages.push( 
        {
            id: -1, // -1 indicates a server message
            message: username + " left the room"
        });

        socket.broadcast.to('lobby').emit('user logout', users, messages);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        var username = socket.name;

        users[socket.userid].status = 0; // 0: OFFLINE

        messages.push( 
            {
                id: -1, // -1 indicates a server message
                message: username + " left the room"
            });

        socket.broadcast.to('lobby').emit('user logout', users, messages);
    });
});
```

Normal logging out works fine, but just exiting the browser gives this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'status' of undefined
```

I've seen a few other threads with this issue, but the solutions I've found don't seem to be fixing this. (This is using Express 4.13.3 and Socket.io 1.3.6)

Comment: Where are you setting `userid`?

Comment: @mscdex, I assign socket.userid on login, and it gets used (successfully) in chat events and logout. It does seem like the built-in socket.id is available after disconnect, I wonder if I just need to store a mapping of socket.ids to usernames somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the root of my problem. Logging io.sockets.connected shows that apparently two sockets are getting created for each client that connects to my server. Only one of these sockets actually emits events, so that's the one that gets assigned a userid and name. Because both sockets disconnect at the same time, the second one throws an error if I try to access its userid attribute.

I still need to learn the purpose of the second socket (or figure out how I'm accidentally creating it), but for now I've fixed the the problem by doing a check to see if the disconnecting socket has the userid attribute before doing the rest of the logout logic.

EDIT:

And the root of *that* problem is that I had two instances of

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

in my index.html. Sigh...